# AltBeacon unstable for OnyxBeacons, cycling through didEnterRegion and didExitRegion repeatedly

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I am building an application using the **[AltBeacon](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library)** library to support **[Onyx Beacons (Beacon One)](http://www.onyxbeacon.com/beacon-hardware/)** and **[Gimbal Beacons (Series 21)](https://store.gimbal.com/collections/beacons/products/s21)**

My test device is a Nexus 7 2013 with Android 4.4.4 KitKat and an Onyx Beacon. The beacon is just sitting less than a meter next to my device and I am not moving it. The beacon is detected and goes to `didEnterRegion` then after a minute or so it goes to `didExitRegion` then the cycle repeats.

We have also tested this on a different device (Samsung Phone) using a different (Onyx) beacon. Still the issue occurs. Note that this only happens on the **[Onyx Beacons (Beacon One)](http://www.onyxbeacon.com/beacon-hardware/)**. The **[Gimbal Beacons (Series 21)](https://store.gimbal.com/collections/beacons/products/s21)** are only triggered once when in range.

Am I using the correct Beacon Parser strings? Am I implementing this correctly? I am really out of ideas and I wanted to support both beacons.

**BaseApplication**

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startService(new Intent(this, BeaconMonitoringService.class));
    }

}
```

**BeaconMonitoringService**

```
public class BeaconMonitoringService extends Service implements BeaconConsumer{

    private Context context;

    private BeaconService service;
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        context = getBaseContext();
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);

        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(15000l);

        String[] beaconParsers = new String[] { "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24", "m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25", "m:2-3=0203,i:14-19l,d:10-13,p:9-9" };

        for(String beacon : beaconParsers){
            Log.i("BeaconService","layout: "+beacon);
            beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(beacon));           
        }
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {

            private String log;

            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Beacon beacon = service.getBeacon(region.getId1().toString(), region.getId2().toString(), region.getId3().toString());
                log = "I just saw a beacon for the first time! "+region.getId1()+" "+region.getId2()+" "+region.getId3();
                Log.i("BeaconService", log);   
                sendNotification(beacon);
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                Beacon beacon = service.getBeacon(region.getId1().toString(), region.getId2().toString(), region.getId3().toString());
                log = "I no longer see a beacon";
                Log.i("BeaconService", log);
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {

            }
        });

        List<BackendRegion> regionList = Util.getRegionList();  
        for(BackendRegion region : regionList){
            ArrayList<Beacon> beaconList = region.getBeacons();
            for(Beacon beacon : beaconList){
                try {
                    String beaconString = region.getUuid().toLowerCase() + " " + beacon.getMajor() + " " + beacon.getMinor();
                    service.addBeacon(beacon);
                    beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region(beacon.getIdentifier(), Identifier.parse(region.getUuid()),Identifier.parse(beacon.getMajor()),Identifier.parse(beacon.getMinor())));
                } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void sendNotification(Beacon beacon, InteractiveImage interactiveImage) {
        this.notifBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Sample Beacon")
                .setContentText("A beacon was detected")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);
        notifBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(beacon.getId()), notifBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

**Log**

```
12-11 15:45:24.103 I/BeaconService: I just saw a beacon for the first time! 20cae8a0-a9cf-11e3-a5e2-0800200c9a66 7 44512
12-11 15:45:24.784 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:45:39.698 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:45:39.709 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:45:40.830 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:45:55.794 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:45:55.804 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:45:56.985 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:46:11.920 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:46:11.950 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:46:13.091 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:46:27.996 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:46:28.016 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:46:29.147 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:46:29.227 I/BeaconService: I no longer see a beacon
12-11 15:46:44.121 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:46:44.141 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:46:44.402 I/BeaconService: I just saw a beacon for the first time! 20cae8a0-a9cf-11e3-a5e2-0800200c9a66 7 44512
12-11 15:46:45.282 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:47:00.197 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:47:00.197 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:47:01.328 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:47:16.343 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:47:16.363 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:47:17.514 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:47:32.418 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:47:32.428 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:47:33.540 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:47:48.494 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:47:48.504 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:47:49.635 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:48:04.620 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:48:04.630 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:48:05.771 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:48:20.706 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:48:20.706 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:48:21.827 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:48:36.821 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:48:36.831 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:48:37.962 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:48:52.917 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:48:52.927 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:48:54.058 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:49:09.003 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
12-11 15:49:09.003 D/BluetoothAdapter: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
12-11 15:49:10.154 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
12-11 15:49:10.214 I/BeaconService: I no longer see a beacon
```

Answer (score 2):

A few tips:

- **Check the advertising rate of the Onyx Beacon One.**  For best results, beacons should advertise at a standard 10Hz.  Some manufacturers slow down this advertising rate to save battery life.  If you have a beacon that is advertising at 1Hz or less often, it can start to be missed periodically by beacon scanners.  (Not 100% of packets are detected due to bluetooth radio noise.)
- If you find that the advertising rate is 1 Hz or less, **increase the advertising rate** if possible and the issue should go away.
- If you cannot increase the advertising rate of the beacon, you can **slow down the scan rate of the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/)** to give it more time to collect beacon packets.  By default, it uses a scan cycle of 1.1 seconds.  You can use a line of code like below to slow this down to 5 seconds.  This will work more reliably with beacons that don't advertise very often, but will also give you slower response times to region entries/exits. `beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(5000l);`

Comment: Should I change the `setBackgroundScanPeriod` as well?

Comment: The default backround scan period is already longer, but you can increase it to 60000l to be extra sure you'll detect the beacon.

Comment: As much as I want to accept this as an answer , I tried slowing down the scan rate but the problem still persist

Comment: Do you know the advertising rate of the beacon?  What did you slow the scan rate to?

Comment: beacon frequency is 1000ms which is equivalent to 1Hz I used `beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(50001);`  Is the last digit on `5000l` really an L ? I used a 1.

Comment: If you want to set the scan period to 5 seconds, then yes, you must have an "el" on the end, not a "one".  The " el" indicates it is a long integer.  Setting it to 5000l will make the San period be 5 secs.  Setting to 50001 (note one at the end) will set it to 50.001 secs, which will not work well.